# How can I convert a string to a float from a textbox CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

this my method post code

```
  <form method="post" action='<?php echo site_url('project/save')?>'>
    <input name="number" type="text" maxlength="4">
```

my insert query code in controller

```
$data=array('number'=>$this->input->post('number')

    $this->db->insert('tb_data',$data);
```

view code on

```
    <?php
    $i=1;
        foreach ($row as $r) {
            echo "<tr>

                <td>$r->number</td>

                  </tr>";
                  $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't using db->insert on controller. Second: Active Record on codeigniter doesn't have issues with types, it's all parsed before the sql query mounted by Active Record. Third: Where are your nama input? Without the column's name obviously codeigniter will show an error.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre ah that nama input i just wrong to posting it on here so that no need parsed it?? or do before post?

Comment: What's the column name that you want to store that number? Is really number?

Active Record's works with: index = column name / value = column value

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre well is real number but on textbox html but that from input from user,still not get it that active record work

Comment: Whats the error showing and show your database schema here please

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre no error just the result is show is not float on that number view, sory i can't  show my schema cuz old phpmyadmin http://imgur.com/Ud2qQNE that number is as to(pendidikan,medical,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an column named number in your table with float type
- Create an model with an insert function, after that, in Controller:

  ```
  <?php
  $this->load->model('Modelname_model');
  $data=array('number'=>$this->input->post('number')

  $this->modelname_model->set($data);
  ```

In your frontend, use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
 <?php
//EXAMPLES
// english notation (default)
//$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
//$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56


    $i=1;
        foreach ($row as $r) {
            echo "<tr>

                <td>" . number_format($r->number, 2, ',', ' ') . "</td>

                  </tr>";
                  $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> number_format();

To disply number in float format in your view.

In your view page change

```
$foo = $r->number;
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');
```